# What does this code do? (2)

Tags: php, foreach

I don't understand the => part.

```
foreach ($_POST[‘tasks’] as $task_id => $v) {
```

What does it do in a foreach loop?

Comment: I would recommend reading the language documentation before asking questions here. You can find the PHP language documentation at http://us3.php.net/manual/en/index.php

Comment: This is a good question, as it is specific, clear, and many people will want to know the answer to it

Comment: cobbal: That's true, but it's awfully basic. I never downvoted it, and don't intend to, but I can see where the downvoters are coming from. There are some things that can be answered better in language docs than here on SO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A foreach loops goes through each item in the array, much like a for loop. In this instance, the $task_id is the key and the $v is the value. For instance:

```
$arr = array('foo1' => 'bar1', 'foo2' => 'bar2');
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
  echo $key; // Outputs "foo1" the first time around and "foo2" the second.
  echo $value; // Outputs "bar1" the first time around and" bar2" the second.
}
```

If no keys are specified, like in the following example, it uses the default index keys like so:

```
$arr = array('apple', 'banana', 'grape');
foreach ($arr as $i => $fruit)
{
  echo $i; // Echos 0 the first time around, 1 the second, and 2 the third.
  echo $fruit;
}

// Which is equivalent to:
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
{
  echo $i;
  echo $arr[$i];
}
```

Comment: looks more like a map than an array.

Comment: @Pablo: PHP 'arrays' are very useful little things, and can be used as a map or an array.

Comment: Actually, I think it's better to say that all PHP arrays are associative arrays. By default, the key is a 0-based integer value, but you can make it anything you want to.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, all arrays are associative arrays. For each key and value pair in the array, the key is assigned to $task_id and the value is assigned to $v. If you don't specify another key, the key is a 0-based integer index, however it can be anything you want to, as long as the key is only used once (trying to reuse it will mean overwriting the old value with a new value).

Comment: I'm not sure that your understanding of the syntax is correct... ?

Comment: It is. $task_id is the key, and $v is the value mapped to that key. An array in PHP is an associative array.

Comment: Although yes, my wording should be improved. Let me do that.

Comment: OK. The wording of your answer suggests that $task_id and $v have the same value.

Comment: I think that's significantly better.

Answer (score 2):

From the context, it looks like `$_POST['tasks']` is an array of some sort. That foreach() takes each key/value pair in that array, and places the key in `$task_id` and the value in `$v`. For instance, if you had:

```
$a['q'] = "Hi";
$a[4] = "BLAH";
```

In the first iteration, `$task_id` would be `'q'`, and `$v` would be `"Hi"`. In the second iteration, `$task_id` would be `4`, and `$v` would be `"BLAH"`.